# Server 2012 DFS Replication throttling values

Tags: windows-server-2012, replication, dfs, dfs-r

Is there any way, via registry edit or something, to throttle the replication throughput by values other than what is listed in the drop-down menu? I would particularly like a 10Mbps or 12Mbps option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff,

Not that I'm aware of, the values are pretty specific based on table of hex values from `0x0` to `0xF`with corresponding bandwidth constraints.

[image]

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx